# Is it possible to create a monthly budget vs actuals chart on MacOS Numbers?

Tags: numbers

I'm creating a yearly budget sheet on numbers where I have a table like this:

```
|             |      January     |     February     |       March      |
|             | ---------------- | ---------------- | ---------------- |
| Description | Actuals | Budget | Actuals | Budget | Actuals | Budget |
| ----------- | ---------------- | ---------------- | ---------------- |
| Groceries   |   $ 300 |  $ 250 |   $ 200 |  $ 250 |   $ 243 |  $ 250 |
```

I am trying to create a chart/graph where I can compare the budget vs the actual on each month. Either a big chart/graph with all the months one next to each other or, ideally, a graph for a single month, with a context selector to select a different month.

I've done some googling to see if I could find how to do it, but I keep finding basic examples of budgeting. I'm now wondering whether MacOS Numbers is not the right tool for this, or maybe I need to have many tables, 1 per month, instead of a big table.

Any thoughts?

### EDIT:

I’ll post pictues of what I tried, and what I would like to have.

#### What I played with

[image: What I get]

#### What I’d like to do

##### A graph with totals per month

[image: Table of totals, per month]

##### A graph with breakdown, with a month selector

[image]

Is it possible, or is it too complicated for MacOS Numbers?

Comment: AskDifferent works best if you have a precise and specific question about a practical problem. In general this seems absolutely doable, but its hard to answer your question in more detail, because it is very unclear what your actual problem is. If you set up your table like what you have described above what is your problem?

Comment: good point, i’ll be more specific

Comment: @X_841 I’ve updated my question to post what I got and what I would like to do

Comment: What is the difference between the graph you have and your first manual drawing?

Comment: It may be a little thing, but the labels are weird, and even thought the total show implicitly (by adding rows on top of each other), I’d like it to be just the total (single color). Perhaps I just chose the wrong graph? I’ll keep trying

Comment: In the graph image, I wish I could group the bars so that both bars from January are closer together, separated from the bars for February

Comment: I think that part of the problem is table. Table is for records (row). Records have labels (columns).  For display the records in a way you want use Organize/Categories.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers would be one of the best tools for this task given the tools it provides and its ease of use. There is even a template provided with Numbers called "Personal Budget" as you can see in the picture below.

To use that Numbers template, go to File -> New in the Numbers menu at the top and scroll down a bit to get the "Personal Finance" category. Double-click on "Personal Budget" icon under that category to open up the template and customize it according to your needs.

[image]

Comment: Hi Alper, I understand there’s a template, but I’m trying to accomplish something a bit more complex. I’ve updated my question with pictures to better convey the idea of what I’m trying to do.

Comment: Numbers might be the best tool IF and only if you're more familiar with it than with Excel or LibreOffice.  There's not really a lot of difference in functionality between them.